# In django send_mass mail creates a new http connection everytime it sends a mail

Tags: django, mandrill, django-email

I have a use case where I need to send 16000+ users unique mails. To do this I am using mandrill api( djrill). To make it more efficient and optimized I am trying to use send_mass_mail functionality along with celery.

While doing so I was checking the celery logs and found that for each email, the celery worker is creating a new http connection.

```
[2015-06-22 14:23:30,745: INFO/Worker-4] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): mandrillapp.com
[2015-06-22 14:23:31,521: INFO/Worker-4] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): mandrillapp.com
[2015-06-22 14:23:32,162: INFO/Worker-4] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): mandrillapp.com
```

This will be crippling for our network and will consume a lot of bandwidth.

Here is my code to do the same

```
@shared_task
def test_email_mass(merge_vars):

    messages = []   

    if DEBUG:
        for k,v in merge_vars.iteritems():
            message = []
            print v['content']

            message.append(title)                                        
            message.append(v['content'])
            message.append('foo@too.com')
            message.append([k])           
            messages.append(tuple(message))
        send_mass_mail(tuple(messages), fail_silently=False)
```

I was expecting that the above code will create only a single http connection.

Edit :
I tried the following too.

```
 connection = get_connection()
    if DEBUG:
        for k,v in merge_vars.iteritems():
            message = []

            msg = EmailMessage(from_email="soo@too.com", subject=title)
            msg.template_name = "standard"
            msg.to = [k]
            msg.from_name = from_name
            messages.append(msg)              
    connection.send_messages(messages)
    connection.close()
```

It still shows that it creates a new http connection everytime.

Comment: Djrill currently creates a new requests connection for each message, so this is the expected behavior right now. I just opened an [issue in Djrill](https://github.com/brack3t/Djrill/issues/94) to change this for multiple messages on a single Django email backend connection. (A pull request would be welcome if you feel like tackling it yourself.) Until then, another option _might_ be to use Mandrill's own python library instead of Djrill -- I'm not sure if that gives more control over connections.

Comment: (Also, I'm assuming there's some technical reason you've selected Mandrill over MailChimp. For sending 16K messages--even with unique personalization--a bulk mailer like MailChimp is often a better choice than a transactional mailer like Mandrill for deliverability.)

Comment: @medmunds I will create a new pull request for this. Thanks

Comment: @medmunds I have added a fix for the above issue which seems to be working well. I have created a pull request for the same. This is my first time contributing to a open source project. Please forgive me if there are mistakes. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @akash-deshpande -- that's a nice improvement to Djrill, and will be included in Djrill v2.0. Congrats on your first open source contribution! I'll follow up with you over on GitHub.